# Cannot create Google Meet link in Google Calendar envent using Service Account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, google-meet

I have configured a service account and successfully created an event using the Google Calendar API. However, I am facing an issue where the Google Meet link (the conference) is not being generated along with the event ( can see the event in the Google Calendar and need to create the Google Meeting manually).
I am sending a POST request to the following endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CalendarID}/events`

I have followed all the necessary steps as outlined below:

Enabled Domain-Wide Delegation for the service account:

1. Logged into https://admin.google.com/ using a G Suite account.

- Navigated to Security -> API Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation.
- Added a new entry and set the client ID of the service account (which consists of only numbers).
- Set the following scopes: [list of scopes]
- Assigned the "Service Account Token Creator" role to the user:

2. Visited https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin.

- Selected the project and went to IAM in the left menu.
- Choose the account to be impersonated and clicked on "Edit".
- Added the "Service Account Token Creator" role.
- Enabled domain delegation for the account following the steps mentioned in this guide: [link to delegation guide]
- Created a Calendar in the account to be impersonated:

3. Logged into https://calendar.google.com/ using the email that should own the calendar (I used a different account, not the one I was impersonating).

- Created a new calendar.
- Shared the calendar with the service account, granting it permissions to modify and manage the calendar.
- Shared the calendar with the account to be impersonated, granting it permissions to modify and manage the calendar.

I encountered a similar problem documented here:https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2751, but I did not find a solution. Although I found indications that service accounts might be unable to create the conference, I have not found official documentation from Google confirming this limitation. Can you assist me in resolving this issue?